# Documentation of angular project using compodoc

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, documentation

I am trying to document my Angular + Typescript application. I'm using Compodoc for that. I installed compodoc using npm by running the command

```
   'npm install -g compodoc'. And added 

   "compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p src/tsconfig.json"
```

in my scripts in package.json. When I run npm run compodoc I'm getting this error

PS D:\Moya Proj\VITMOBAPPHYD2016> npm run compodoc

> moya-app@0.0.0 compodoc D:\Moya Proj\VITMOBAPPHYD2016
>   compodoc -p src/tsconfig.json

```
                                            _
                                           | |
    ___    ___    _ __ ___    _ __     ___     __| |   ___     ___
   / __|  / _ \  | '_ ` _ \  | '_ \   / _ \   / _` |  / _ \   / __|
  | (__  | (_) | | | | | | | | |_) | | (_) | | (_| | | (_) | | (__   0.0.41
   \___|  \___/  |_| |_| |_| | .__/   \___/   \__,_|  \___/   \___|
                       | |
                       |_|
```

> [11:08:57] "tsconfig.json" file was not found in the current directory npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! moya-app@0.0.0 compodoc: compodoc -p src/tsconfig.json
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the moya-app@0.0.0 compodoc script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR! C:\Users\Shahid.tabrez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-15T05_38_57_267Z-debug.log

Should I add anything to my tsconfig.json Or is there anything wrong in what I've done.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this video out: https://youtu.be/xJSKZ1DE4Go Simon explains in detail how it is installed

Comment: Thank You but ive found the answer. 
I should have ran this 'compodoc -p ./tsconfig.json'

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my life. I was also getting tsconfig.json not found error, but tried running `compodoc -p ./tsconfig.json` instead, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether the path  is correctly mentioned under "scripts" object in package.json file. By default the path is "src/tsconfig.app.json". If your tsconfig.app.json is not at the mentioned path, modify the path and check, it will work definitely